# Storing php cookie values in csv file on a new line each time program is run

Tags: php, csv

For a leaderboard for a game I am trying to use a csv file to store the cookie value for username and the corresponding user's score. The code seems to be functional when its runs first but when another user completes the quiz the line of the csv file written with the previous user's username and score is overwritten and replace with the current user's username and score.

```
<?php session_start();

 $scoreCookie = $_COOKIE['scoreCookieToPost'];

 $leaderboard_data = array (
 $_COOKIE['usernamecookie'],
 $scoreCookie
);

$file = fopen("leaderboarddata.csv","w");


fputcsv($file, $leaderboard_data);


fclose($file);

?>
```

What changes would need to be made so each new submission would be put in a new row in the csv file and the first line would say Username,Score.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to use the append mode of `fopen` 'a'.

```php
<?php session_start();

 $scoreCookie = $_COOKIE['scoreCookieToPost'];

 $leaderboard_data = array (
 $_COOKIE['usernamecookie'],
 $scoreCookie
);

$file = fopen("leaderboarddata.csv","a"); // a


fputcsv($file, $leaderboard_data );


fclose($file);

?>
```

Comment: When I open the page again and use a new username and get another score, it seems to still overwrite the previous entry in line 1 of the csv file. Is there a way to get around this? (maybe something to do with saving the csv file).

Comment: Just saw the change you made I used "a" instead of "w+" and now this is working thank you very much!

Comment: Actually with  `fopen("leaderboarddata.csv","a")` you're opening the file in append mode, so it should work.
Yes sorry for that... I confused the flags...